# Move BitBucket repository to cPanel

Tags: git, bitbucket, cpanel, move

I have a repository that is currently hosted on BitBucket, that I want to move to Git cPanel version control (run by my hosting company), so I can then delete my account on BitBucket and host all my repositories in a single location.
I do not want to have any links/ties to the original BitBucket repository, but I do need to retain all of the repository history.

I did try...
git push -u origin master
...but this made me nervous...
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first change your origin remote url with the new cPanel one

```
git remote set-url origin <new-cpanel-gitrepo-url>
```

And then push like you were doing before

Comment: Thanks. I ran the commands "git remote set-url origin <new-cpanel-gitrepo-url>", followed by "git push -u origin master".

Answer (score 1):

first, to retain the only certain number of commits, you can use either

`git merge --interactive` or `--squash`, all data about it can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

second, to push to Cpanel you add it either by adding new remote to your remote

`git remote add <your-remote-name> <url of your cpanel>`

or changing the url of the origin remote you added by

`git remote set-url origin <url of cpanel>`